# Simple html form, and update php - Not updating database

Tags: sql, database, forms

I have a simple form, and some PHP that uses the form info to update the database.
It's all very simple, but not working.

My HTML form:

```
<form action="../settings/updateSettings.php" method="post">
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $usersEMAIL ?>"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $usersPASSWORD ?>"><br>
        Location: <input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $usersLOCATION ?>"><br>
        Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $usersPOSTCODE ?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Information">
    </form>
```

and here is my php:

```
<?php
    require_once('../scripts/include.php'); //logs into database

    $who = 65; //temp value to be deleted

    $formEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $formPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $formLocation = $_POST['location'];
    $formPostcode = $_POST['postcode'];

    mysql_query("
    UPDATE tbl_users SET email = $formEmail WHERE id = $who
    ");

?>
```

Comment: Need more details to be of any help. Do you get any errors or warnings? Does anything go into the MySQL database? How about if you hardcode the query and run the php? Does it work then?

Comment: No error messages, it just doesn't update the database value. Very frustrating indeed. (Obviously, I'm currently only trying to update using the email form field)

Comment: It must just be the actual mysql_query section that isn't working, because I can echo the value being move between pages no problem.

Comment: Okay, looks like you need to add quotes before and after `$formEmail` in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sql query is missing single quotes. should be something like:

```
mysql_query("
UPDATE tbl_users SET email = '$formEmail' WHERE id = $who
");
```

Comment: If this is the error I'll eat my hat! - Trying it now..

Comment: if you do have an error log, it would tremendously help debug.

Comment: Lucky for me, I do not own a hat... it worked!

Comment: @ElaineAdams you don't need quotes around `$who` if it's a numeric type in the database